# Is this a double document ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, document

I'm working with a script and have found the following, which I really can't find any info of what it means

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(e) {


       ... bla bla bla ...

    });
}) (jQuery);
```

Is `(function($){}) (jQuery);` the same as `$(function () {});` ? and if so, why would somebody define twice `document.ready` ?

Comment: probably trying to work around some OTHER js library redefining `$` away from jquery, by passing the entire jquery object in as a parameter to this "ready" function, so it's guaranteed to be jquery when the internal ready function actually fires.

Comment: could be so @MarcB as many other libraries are being loaded. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not the same. It's an anonymous function which is being passed the jQuery object, to insure that it is available as the local variable `$` within the scope of the function, even if the global variable `$` is overwritten by another library. It is completely different than `$(function () { })` and `$(document).ready(function () { })`.

This particular pattern is recommended in the [jQuery plugin authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) documentation:

> *[When authoring a plugin]* it's a best practice to pass jQuery to an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) that maps it to the dollar sign so it can't be overwritten by another library in the scope of its execution.
>
> ```
> (function( $ ) {
>   $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
>  
>    // Do your awesome plugin stuff here
>
>  };
> })( jQuery );
> ```

Answer (score 2):

> Is `(function($){}) (jQuery);` the same as `$(function () {});` ?

No. The first is immediate invocation of an anonymous function, used primarily for preventing pollution of the global scope. In this case, it's also used to make sure that `$` is a reference to `jQuery`, without worrying about overwriting `$` elsewhere.

The second is [the shorthand for binding a document ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) with jQuery.

More reading:

- [What is the purpose of a self executing function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript/2867041#2867041)
- [What is the reason for this JavaScript immediate invocation pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475578/what-is-the-reason-for-this-javascript-immediate-invocation-pattern)

Answer (score 2):

No it isn't, `(function($){}) (jQuery);` is an IIFE(Immediately invoked function expression) passing jQuery as a parameter and using `$` to represent it in the function scope so that no conflicts will occur if another library that uses `$` is loaded without using jQuery.noConflict.

Answer (score 2):

Nope

```
(function(){})();
```

is executed as soon as the browser encounters that script.
.ready() is an event that is triggered after the entire document is parsed

Answer (score 1):

No it's not. It is a closure with a document ready handler inside it. It is used to ensure that the `$` within the enclosure is reserved for jQuery and does not interfere with any other library.

Answer (score 0):

A nice clear explanation here;

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/what-heck-is-function-jquery.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Link-only answers are strongly discouraged. Your answer needs to include all the information required to answer the question, which may then be * supplemented* with links.