# What does (jQuery) mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently noticed in a JavaScript recently that there was a **`(jQuery)`** included at the end of the script. What does it mean and What does it do ?

```
(function($) {
    //  code here
    ................
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Context matters. I'm sure that wasn't the complete statement.

Comment: You did not do any research, did you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would look something like this:

```
(function($){
  //your code here
})(jQuery)
```

It is to make sure that the dollar sign (`$`) refers to the `jQuery` object. Sometimes other libraries might change it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking what jQuery itself is:

http://jquery.com/

> jQuery is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library. It makes things like HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling, animation, and Ajax much simpler with an easy-to-use API that works across a multitude of browsers. With a combination of versatility and extensibility, jQuery has changed the way that millions of people write JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you've seen something like this -

```
(function(anArgument) {
    // lots of code
    ................
})(jQuery);
```

What is does is that, it creates an anonymous function with one argument and then immediately invokes it with the `jQuery` object as its parameter.

You'll learn more about it if you go to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475578/what-is-the-reason-for-this-javascript-immediate-invocation-pattern).

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery object :)

From the JQuery doc:

By default, jQuery uses "$" as a shortcut for "jQuery"

So, using $("#id") or jQuery("#id") is the same